# API download data, recommendations?

Tags: python, database, string, pandas, extract

I am trying to decode data from an API, I just cannot think of a clean way to extract the value and time values. I been trying to do string manipulations, but ends up very complex.

```
{"max_scale": "0", "min_scale": "0", "graph_label": "Light Level", "average": "1", "length_of_time": "3600", "upper_warn": "1000", "lower_warn": "30", "cached": false, "values": 
 [{"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170219}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170159}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170099}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170039}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169979}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169919}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169859}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169799}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169739}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169679}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169619}, 
  {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531166679}], 
  "timestamp_to": "1531170222.798", "format_string": "%f Lux"}
```

Comment: That looks an awful lot like JSON. Have you tried using [a JSON parser?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: Of course instead of just guessing that it looks like JSON and therefore almost surely is, you should probably either (a) read the docs for the API you're using, or (b) read the HTTP headers (assuming it's an HTTP API). I'll bet they both tell you that this is JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in JSON format. Use the python [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) encoder/decoder to load this data. It will turn it into a dictionary, and something like

```
my_json_dict['values']
```

will return you that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `json` module for this, or you could just munge the data yourself and turn it into a dict since it is practically one already. Then all you would need to do is loop over it like so:

```
    data = {"max_scale": "0", "min_scale": "0", "graph_label": 
            "Light Level", "average": "1", "length_of_time": "3600",
            "upper_warn": "1000", "lower_warn": "30", "cached": 'false', 
            "values": 
              [{"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170219}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170159}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170099}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531170039}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169979}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169919}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169859}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169799}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169739}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169679}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531169619}, 
               {"value": 0.0, "time": 1531166679}], 
               "timestamp_to": "1531170222.798", "format_string": "%f Lux"}

for item in data['values']:
    time, value = item['time'], item['value']
```